# GCPのObject Detection APIを動かしたところ静的IPアドレスの認証でつまりました

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud, google-compute-engine

第9回　驚きの性能？！　Obeject Detection APIで物体認識に挑戦
https://book.mynavi.jp/manatee/detail/id=76951

にならってGCPを動かしてみました。
アプリが使用可能になるところまで順調に進み、
最後にVMインスタンスで作成した外部IPアドレスにアクセスしたところ、
認証を求められました。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

SSHのパスワード認証方式になるかと思いますが、
このユーザー名とパスワードはどこで得ることができるのでしょうか？？？
GCP初心者に是非助言をお願い致します。

Comment: ありがとうございます！
decorator.pyファイルで設定したユーザー名とパスワードで認証に成功しました。
今後ともよろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SSH の認証ではなく、ウェブアプリ自体に簡易認証の仕組みをつけているのではないでしょうか。

以下、[質問者さんが参考になさったページ](https://book.mynavi.jp/manatee/detail/id=76951)からの引用です。

> このアプリでは、Webブラウザから接続した際に簡易的な認証処理が行われるようになっています。ファイル /opt/object_detection_app/decorator.py をエディタで開いて、次の 'username' と 'passw0rd' の部分を書き換えることで、認証用のユーザー名とパスワードを変更することができます。このままのユーザー名／パスワードで使用する場合は、書き換えなくても構いません。